# Create dynamic named range in VBA that references ListObjects table

Tags: vba, excel, named-ranges, listobject

I need to create a named range that refers to the last few rows of data in a ListObject table. While I can do it manually from the ribbon (Formulas > Define Name) I have to do this across 20 sheets with 3 ranges each.

When I try this using VBA I get error 1004 and a warning that there's a problem with the formula and to remove the "=" if I'm not trying to enter a formula. Any ideas how to resolve this?

Open a fresh Sheet1 to try my code. It'll create a ListObjects table and will try to create the Named range.

```
Sub test2()
    Dim wks As Worksheet, tbl As ListObject
    Dim arr()

    arr = [{"Date","1/1/2016","2/1/2016","3/1/2016","4/1/2016";"Green",100,200,300,400;"Yellow",350,250,150,50;"Red",10,7,5,3}]
    Set wks = ActiveSheet
    wks.Range("a1:d5") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr)

    Set tbl = wks.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, wks.Range("a1").CurrentRegion, , xlYes)
    tbl.Name = "tblTix"

    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add "rngRedLast3Mos", "=OFFSET(tblTix,MATCH(MAX(tblTix[Date]),tblTix[Date],1)-3,MATCH(""Red"",tblTix[#Headers],0)-1,3,1)"  'THIS FAILS
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add "rngRedLast3Mos", "=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,2,3,3,1)"  'THIS WORKS
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add "rngRedLast3Mos", "=Sheet1!$D$3:$D$5"  'THIS ALSO WORKS

    Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.Names("rngRedLast3Mos").RefersTo
    Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Range("rngRedLast3Mos").Address

End Sub
```

If I manually define the range in Name Manager, I can assign this reference, and it works:

```
=OFFSET(tblTix,MATCH(MAX(tblTix[Date]),tblTix[Date],1)-3,MATCH("Red",tblTix[#Headers],0)-1,1,1)
```

I don't understand what's going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add "rngRedLast3Mos", _
"=OFFSET(tblTix,MATCH(MAX(tblTix[Date]),tblTix[Date],1)-3,MATCH(""Red"",tblTix[#Headers],0)-1,3,1)"
```

to

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="rngRedLast3Mos", RefersToR1C1:= _
"=OFFSET(tblTix,MATCH(MAX(tblTix[Date]),tblTix[Date],1)-3,MATCH(""Red"",tblTix[#Headers],0)-1,3,1)"
```

Do that for the rest as well

Comment: Yahoo, it works! Thank you! I was trying to figure it out for a few hours. Can you give a little explanation why that works? Microsoft's documentation isn't very helpful in this regard.

Comment: I just added `Name:=` and `RefersToR1C1:=`. I know it is weird because by default the 1st 2 parameters are name and refersto and in most cases you do not need to specify them but in this case you have to.. to make it work